# How to keep only one blank line between a blank line and a separate line in python?

Tags: python

```
exam = float(input("Exam total: "))
print('\n')
print("----------------------")
```

Here I got two blank lines between the separate line and the printed blank line. So how to get only one blank line?
or, if you run the program, the printed blank line seems like two blank lines in the space, as my pylint check reminding.

Comment: Can you post a sample of the desired output?

Comment: Just use `print()`. It prints one empty line. If you add `\n` the number of empty lines become two.

Comment: The [default argument `end` for `print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) contains `'\n'`, so if you don't supply anything, it prints that.

Comment: And instead of `print("----------------------")`, you can simply use `print('-' * 23)` or `print(23 * '-')`, more readable IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Ugly, but does the trick:

```
exam = float(input("Exam total:"))
print("\n ----------------------")
```

Output:

```
Exam total: 4

 ----------------------
```

Edit: I'd recommend the answers suggested in the comments thread to your question over mine